# react-native android: Debug mode is broken

Tags: android, react-native, debugging

I think my debug mode for android is kinda broken. I cannot open the debug menu, event though I have yellow-orange boxes for warnings on my device (which tells that i'm running the app on debug mode). No chrome tab opens with a debugger when i run a `react-native run-android`.

The metro bundler doesn't seem to bundle anything by the way. I used to have a green progress bar but now nothing, even though my app does start on my device.

[image: metro bundler]

`react-native log-android` gives me logs from the app, as if I was looking a the console.

`adb shell input keyevent 82` doesn't do anything.

React Native version:

```
System:
      OS: Windows 10
      CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU 
@ 2.20GHz
      Memory: 6.96 GB / 19.74 GB
    Binaries:
      Yarn: 1.17.3 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
      npm: 6.4.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD 
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: Version  3.5.0.0 AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548


"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.9",
```

I wasn't able to find anything online on this issue. I don't know what caused that, I've just joined the project and the repository is a mess...

Did you guys had this issue before ?

Comment: There should be another cmd as well from which you initiate the project start mechanism. Can you please share its content. Thank you

Comment: I assure you there is none !

Comment: From where do you execute the command than ?